# NetSuite Update Customer subscription entries

Tags: netsuite, sublist

I'm triing to update customer subscriptions list in netsuite.

```
var itemCount = recLead.getLineItemCount('subscriptions');
for (var i = 1; i < itemCount; i++ ) {  recLead.setCurrentLineItemValue('subscriptions', 'subscribed', 'T');}
```

But error throws:
Notice (SuiteScript)
You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation. You are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning on using the "current" line item function, then you do need to select the line to use.  As below:

```
var itemCount=recLead.getLineItemCount('subscriptions');
for(var i=1;i<=itemCount;i++){
  recLead.selectLineItem('item',i);
  recLead.setCurrentLineItemValue('subscriptions','subscribed','T');
  recLead.commitLineItem('item');
}
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to do it that way, you can use setLineItemValue, instead.

```
var itemCount=recLead.getLineItemCount('subscriptions');
  for(var i=1;i<=itemCount;i++){
  recLead.setLineItemValue('subscriptions','subscribed',i,'T');
}
```

Both, effectively, work the same.

BTW, since you have to start at row 1, you need to make sure you use i<=itemCount.  Otherwise, if there are 10 rows, you will miss the last row.  When you move to 2.0, and start your count at 0, you can use i< itemCount.

Answer (score 2):

Before using setCurrentLineItemValue, you need to select the line using selectLineItem then commitLineItem to save the changes.